# Angular fade in image on click with directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

Trying to fade an image in on click using a directive. The directive works great when the image first appears (initial page load), fading it in nicely, but this does not happen on click, it just switches with no fade. How can I get the directive `fade-in` to work with the `ng-click="onClick()"` event?

I tried adding a timeout around the `$element.addClass("ng-hide-add");` in the `directive`, but it didn't work.

[Here's a plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/6TCWdu?p=preview)

Here's the html:

```
 <img ng-src="img/{{randTarotImg}}.jpg" class="tarot animate-show" ng-click="onClick()" fade-in/>
```

Here's the js:

```
angular.module('TarotApp')
    .controller('TarotCtrl', function ($scope) {

        $scope.tarotImg = [];
          for (var i=1;i<=6;i++) {
          $scope.tarotImg.push(i);
        }  

        $scope.randTarotImg = $scope.tarotImg[Math.floor(Math.random() * $scope.tarotImg.length)];

        $scope.onClick = function() {
              $scope.randTarotImg = $scope.tarotImg[Math.floor(Math.random() * $scope.tarotImg.length)];  
        };

})

    .directive('fadeIn', function($timeout){
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function($scope, $element, attrs){
                $element.addClass("ng-hide-remove");
                $element.on('load', function() {
                    $element.addClass("ng-hide-add"); 
                });
            }
        };
});
```

Here's the css:

```
.animate-show.ng-hide-add, .animate-show.ng-hide-remove {
    transition: all linear 0.5s;
    display: block !important;
}

.animate-show.ng-hide-add.ng-hide-add-active, .animate-show.ng-hide-remove {
    opacity: 0;
}

.animate-show.ng-hide-add, .animate-show.ng-hide-remove.ng-hide-remove-active {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to change image on click and you want fade-in everytime an image loads?

Comment: @ravishankar Yes, exactly. I tried this using a button, but I had the same problem with the directive not firing, (and also tying to get the button to be completely invisible was a challenge) :D , so I went with ng-click instead.

Comment: Adding and removing the class wont get you the results, you need to keep a time lag between them. Try with `setTimeOut()` before adding the `ng-hide-add` class

Comment: @ravishankar Thank you. Can you explain a little more? I'm not sure how to implement this.

Comment: Try looking into `ngModelUpdate`, i think its better way to achieve your result.https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions

Comment: @ravishankar ok thanks. I tried `$element.on('load', function() {
                  $timeout(function() {$element.addClass("ng-hide-add");}, 1000);   });` and it didn't change anything.

Comment: Can you provide a JSFiddle, i might help better if i have that.

Comment: Yes sure thing, here you go. http://plnkr.co/edit/6TCWdu?p=preview Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

In your Directive try this:

```
.directive('fadeIn', function($timeout){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function($scope, $element, attrs){
            $element.addClass("ng-hide-remove");
            $element.on('load', function() {
                $timeout($element.addClass("ng-hide-add"),1000);//Adding timeout
            });
        }
    };
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, nice try, unfortunately not working yet. I wonder why not it seems like a very logical solution.

Comment: Thanks again Ravi, I ended up getting my answer here ==> http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2497-cross-fading-images-with-angularjs.htm